# Delphi application running on Amazon EC2

Tags: delphi, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

I'm very interested in the performance of a Windows application running on Amazon EC2, have anyone done that? if so, please let us know about how good the performance is and the cost.

I hope the question is pretty straight.

Comment: Why is the question titled "DELPHI application"? It really doesn't matter. Delphi, Visual C++ or assembler, it's the same thing, they all produce binary code which performs roughly the same (compared to the speed drop you get from choosing wrong algorithms).

Comment: @himself you're right, however I'm more interested from the point of view of Delphi developers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run a pretty large business on an Amazon EC2 Windows instance. It's an ASP.NET application and not Delphi, but that shouldn't make any difference. All in all you are paying for a machine that's as large as you require, and can also scale it out as needed -- so performance is rarely an issue, and cost is somewhat tied to the size of your customer base.

Comment: thank you, I believe this covers it. just one question, if you ware to create a new web application(for personal or business) would you go for a web host service or would you choose Amazon and why? thank you for your time I appreciate it.

Comment: I would use Amazon EC2 for a new business, but for a very specific reason. I would spin up my app on the smallest/cheapest machine config possible and run everything on a single box. As the application gains customers it may turn out that more memory or CPU is required. Or maybe it's a bad idea to run the server and database on the same box. etc. etc. No problem... Just spin up new machines and continue with the testing. After some time you would get an idea of exactly what's optimal for the app in production and either stay with EC2 (reserved instances) or move to a more permanent VPS host.